# OSX autotools: `aclocal.m4' not being output by `autom4te'

Tags: macos, shell, macports, autotools, m4

I have been trying to build the `freetype2` library in OSX Mavericks for several weeks now, but without success.

The trouble is with using `GNU Autotools` to create the `configure` build script.

I have installed `automake`, `autoconf`, `libtoolize`, `m4` and `perl5` using the macports `port` command.

When executing `aclocal`, there is supposed to be a file created in the `configure` directory that contains Autotools macros: `aclocal.m4`. However, this file is not being output, and the subsequent `glibtoolize` and `autoconf` commands are generating a spurious `configure` script.

The result is: no `aclocal.m4` file, and the usual contents of `./autom4te.cache/traces.*` being dumped at the top of the generated `configure` file (the `traces.*` files are empty).

e.g.:

```
m4trace:configure.ac:14: -1- AC_SUBST([SHELL])
m4trace:configure.ac:14: -1- AC_SUBST_TRACE([SHELL])
m4trace:configure.ac:14: -1- m4_pattern_allow([^SHELL$])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have run the `make check` command, after `configure`, in the latest `autoconf` source tree (2.6.9). This invoked `testsuite`, which output many "FAILED" messages.

The full output can be found here:

[link](http://pastebin.com/4rTg4fTy)

If you have seen similar symptoms before, or can interpret them, please let me know.

Comment: why don't you install freetype from macports?

Comment: @arved I need to cross-compile a custom build of `freetype` for iOS devices (arm7/arm7s).

This is not so much an issue with `freetype`, but one with the `GNU Autotools` and my OSX environment.

Comment: Have you tried running aclocal with --verbose to get an idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: @arved yes, I have tried a variety of `--verbose` and `--debug` options for the Autotools binaries, and run the `testsuite` harness. There is no explicit error message that suggests a solution. It just seems that `autom4te` is outputting spurious `m4trace` messages whenever it is executed.

Comment: Why are you trying to build the configure script?  The configure script should be available in the tarball.  If it is not, file a bug against the package.

Comment: @WilliamPursell there is a bug in the latest tarball, so I need to build from the git repository. The git repository does not contain a prebaked configure script.

Comment: Is the bug known to the maintainers?  If it takes them several weeks to fix such a bug, is this really a package that you want to be using?

Comment: @WilliamPursell the maintainers have been notified, but do not intend to fix non-POSIX file system compatibility. GNU Autotools is a popular precursor to many build processes, so the work around below will have to suffice for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GNU Autotools` does not support execution over a working directory stored on a `FAT32` file system. It results in spurious `m4trace` debug messages being output to the generated `configure` script.

It is unknown why this is, but may be related to the reliance on the `sleep` command to check whether a file has changed. `FAT32` rounds time stamps to the nearest second, where execution and subsequent modification checks may happen on a sub-second timescale.

This has been raised with the development team, but for now, I move my working directory to my `OSX` boot partition before executing `GNU Autotools`.